# Proving the image set of $g$ is open

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $U\subset V$ be open in $\mathbb{R}^k$. Let $f:V \to \mathbb{R}$ be of class $C^r$. Define $g(\mathbf{x})=(\mathbf{x},f(\mathbf{x}))$, for all $\mathbf{x}$ in $V$. Is $g(U)$ necessarily open in the image set of $g$? If not, under what conditions does this hold?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi sorry I meant is $g(U)$ open in the image set of $g$? Otherwise it would be so trivial. I edit now

Comment: You want to know whether $(U,f(U))$ is open in $(V,f(V))$ for $U$ open in $V$. Well, what do the open sets in $(V,f(V))$ look like?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Note that $(x,y) \in g(U)$ if and only if $x \in U$ and $y = f(x)$.

Now, suppose $(x,y) \in g(U)$. Is it possible for $(x,y_1) \in g(U)$ for any $y_1 \neq y$? Based on your answer to that, is it possible to find a ball centered at $(x,y)$ which is contained in $g(U)$?

Comment: sorry I meant is $g(U)$ open in the image set of $g$? Otherwise it would be so trivial. I edit now